# Disable touch scrolling when modal is open

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I'm using full-screen modals on my site on mobile. The problem is that touching the modal will cause the body page to move even though it's overflow:hidden;

Here's what bootstrap says about that:

> Support for overflow: hidden on the  element is quite limited in
>   iOS and Android. To that end, when you scroll past the top or bottom
>   of a modal in either of those devices' browsers, the  content
>   will begin to scroll.

What can I do to prevent that?

Setting the body to position:fixed causes the scroll to jump to the top in an ugly way. What's the best solution if anyone came up with one?

Comment: Do you use jQuery, jQuery Mobile or something like this?

Comment: @seva.rubbo I have jquery but not jqmobile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question myself before.

What I did is changed the body to `overflow:hidden` and fixed `height` equal to modal `height` and remembered document scroll position. After closing the modal, I've applied remembered scroll position back and `height` to `auto`.

It is so complicated because I needed my modals to be bigger than window and I wanted to be able to scroll the modal.